# Save plots generated from fbprophet in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to export the plots generated by facebook prophet methods such as model.plot_components() and model.plot() . However, I have dug the entire Internet and all instructions use the matplotlib method of building the plot from the ground up and then save, etc. For me, it's not possible or very hard in this case because I don't know how to plot those fbprophet functions using plain matplotlib.

Is there a general method to export an existing figure object to a .png file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use **m.plot_components(forecast).savefig('filename.png')** function.

```
df = pd.read_csv(DataFile)
m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=365)
forecast = m.predict(future)
m.plot_components(forecast).savefig('1.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable equal to the prophet plot. It will be a matplotlob plot with all of matplotlib’s functionality available to it. So for example:

```
fig = model.plot(forecast)
fig.savefig('prophetplot.svg')
```